# Create partition table using execute

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql, database-partitioning

I would like to create N partition tables for the last N days. I have created a table like the following

```
create table metrics.my_table (
    id bigserial NOT NULL primary key,
    ...
    logdate date NOT NULL
) PARTITION BY LIST (logdate);
```

Then I have the following function to create those tables:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE function metrics.create_my_partitions(init_date numeric default 30, current_date_parameter timestamp default current_date)
returns void as $$
DECLARE
    partition_date TEXT;
    partition_name TEXT;
begin
    for cnt in 0..init_date loop
        partition_date := to_char((current_date_parameter - (cnt * interval '1 day')),'YYYY-MM-DD');
        raise notice 'cnt: %', cnt;
        raise notice 'partition_date: %', partition_date;
        partition_name := 'my_table_' || partition_date;
        raise notice 'partition_name: %', partition_name;
        EXECUTE format('CREATE table if not exists metrics.%I PARTITION OF metrics.my_table for VALUES IN ($1)', partition_name) using partition_date;
    end loop;
END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

select metrics.create_my_partitions(30, current_date);
```

But it throws the following error in the EXECUTE format line:

```
SQL Error [42P02]: ERROR: there is no parameter $1
```

Any idea on how to create those tables?

Comment: You'll have to use `format` for the value as well, that cannot be a parameter.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe and how can I do that? I tried using %I like with the table name, but it also fails:

EXECUTE format('CREATE table if not exists metrics.%I PARTITION OF metrics.my_table for VALUES IN (%I)', partition_name, partition_date);


SQL Error [0A000]: ERROR: cannot use column reference in partition bound expression

Comment: @Homer you need to format as a literal value for the `IN` expression, not an identifier

Comment: Thank you, it works like the following:
EXECUTE format('CREATE table if not exists metrics.%I PARTITION OF metrics.my_table for VALUES IN  (''%I'')', partition_name, partition_date);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `EXECUTE ... USING ...` option only works for data values in DML commands (`SELECT`,`INSERT`, etc.). Since `CREATE TABLE` is a DDL command, use a parameter in `format()`:

```sql
execute format(
    'create table if not exists metrics.%I partition of metrics.my_table for values in (%L)', 
    partition_name, partition_date);
```